# Program crashes inside the copy constructor of a discriminated union

Tags: c++, crash, unions

So I've been trying to create a discriminated union for my project. Coming from C, I thought it would be trivial... ;)

The structure is named `Message`. It has a `MessageType` and an inner union which holds either a `MessageGet` or a `MessageSet`.

```
enum MessageType {
    MESSAGE_GET,
    MESSAGE_SET
};

struct MessageGet {
    std::string store_name;
    std::vector<uint8_t> key;
};

struct MessageSet {
    std::string store_name;
    std::vector<uint8_t> key;
    std::vector<uint8_t> value;
};

struct Message {
    MessageType type;

    uint64_t sender_id;    

    union U {
        U() : get() {}

        U(const U& other) {
            get = other.get;
            set = other.set;
        }

        ~U() {}

        U& operator=(const U& other) {
            set = other.set;
            get = other.get;
            return *this;
        }

        MessageGet get;

        MessageSet set;
    } as;

    Message() {}

    ~Message() {
        switch (type) {
            case MESSAGE_GET: {
                as.get.~MessageGet();
                break;
            }
            case MESSAGE_SET: {
                as.set.~MessageSet();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Message(MessageGet get, uint64_t sender_id) {
        type = MESSAGE_GET;
        as.get = get;
        sender_id = sender_id;
    }

    Message(MessageSet set, uint64_t sender_id) {
        type = MESSAGE_SET;
        as.set = set;
        sender_id = sender_id;
    }

    Message(const Message& other) {
        type = other.type;
        as = other.as;
        sender_id = other.sender_id;
    }

    Message& operator=(const Message& other) {
        type = other.type;
        as = other.as;
        sender_id = other.sender_id;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

The program crashes elsewhere in the code where I do something like this:

```
Message message(MessageGet {std::move(store_name), std::move(key)}, sender);
messages.push_back(message); // messages is a local std::vector<Message>
```

It doesn't crash with an exception - simply a crash.

I've managed to narrow it down to inside the `Message` copy constructor. After that, have no clue what causes this. Ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: `as.get.~MessageGet();`  `as.set.~MessageSet();` -- What's the reason for calling the destructor explicitly here?  Explicit calls to the destructor are used for `placement-new`, and I don't see anywhere you are doing this.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie They can't get called automatically because the implementation doesn't know which one is valid and which one isn't.

Comment: I think if you use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), a lot of these problems might go away.  In particular, it implements an appropriate copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    U(const U& other) {
        get = other.get;
        set = other.set;
    }
```

This always sets `set` last, making the value of `get` invalid. When you set one of the members of a union, it invalidates all the others. That's what makes a union different from a struct.

Where you have:

```
    as = other.as;
```

You have to change that to copy only the valid member.

Comment: *"...  That's what makes a union different from a struct. ..."* - yeah I know, don't know why I wrote it like that... :)

Comment: I took your suggestion to replace `as = other.as` with a `switch(type) {...}` to only set the correct member of the union based on the type. Seems it solved the problem. Can you elaborate why that might have been the problem? Why and how is it illegal to just set a union directly, as in `as = other.as`?

Comment: @AvivCohn `as` is default constructed (constructs `get`), then you assign to `get` (which is OK), then the `push_back` will call the copy constructor, where you access `set` which is not the active member of the union. (In this particular case, most likely `value` occupies unintialized memory. At the very least it hasn't been constructed. When you try to copy `value` BOOM!)

Comment: @AvivCohn How could it possibly work? How would `as = other.as;` know whether it's supposed to construct one vector or two vectors? And your destructor might destroy one vector and might destroy two vectors -- so it had better get it right!

Comment: @DavidSchwartz @1201ProgramAlarm I see. Coming from C, I keep forgetting that in C++ symbols like `=` actually imply some function calling behind the scenes. In this case, call the (non existent) copy assignment operator of `U`, which would construct things. I was used to the C mindset, where `as = other.as` should simply copy bytes around, so what does it matter which union member I look at them through. I learned something today! Thanks guys.